# How to set countdown timer for playing song by using streaming in android

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am trying to set count down timer for streaming song from url.Countdown timer is Working, but when data is not buffered because of slow internet speed the countdown timer is not stopped. If anyone have idea about that please help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get total duration and current duration for media player like this

```
long totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000; // converted to seconds

long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
```

and to get count down timer you can use this

```
long  counDown = currentDuration  - totalDuration ;
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: but how to stop and then start the countdown timer when data is not buffered because of slow internet speed

Comment: It is will stop because `currentDuration` stop when data is not buffered.